# How to scatter objects based on texture color data with Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So the idea is to interpolate a heavily pixelated image into 4-6 tints of grey.

Based on the value of that local pixel I want to add a specific object.
The plane will be subdivided into the corresponding pixel sections. *(This should make it easier to distribute the objects in my opinion)*

Is there a way to achieve this using geometry nodes?

See image below for the result I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: i think it is not possible with a pixel dependency because Blender works on vertex/faces/edges basis.

Comment: @Chris I feel that there should be a way to do this given we have an ''Attribute Color Ramp'' & ''Attribute Sample Texture'' node. I will be subdividing the image so that the edges are touching the pixel borders, this way I would be able to distribute on faces.
Just need to figure out how to extract multiple specific color values from the texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you translate the positions (in this case the *Faces* of a grid) to a range of *0-1*, you can capture the color values at certain positions of an image.

You can then translate these positions directly into indexes with the node `Map Range`, which will select the corresponding object from your collection as the value for *Instance Index* with the node `Instance on Points`.

[image]

Here is a summary of the node group that leads to the described result:

[image]

Here is the blend file:

[image]